# trouble with stack class in c++

Tags: c++

When making my own stack class I can't get the driver to work and I'm guessing it has something to do with my stack class. It's pretty straight forward but I'm not exactly sure how to use pointers or anything in c++.

Driver :

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "dynStack.h"
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        dynStack stack;

        cout << "Stack has been created!";
        cout << endl;
        double a = 1.0;
        double b = 2.0;
        double c = 3.0;
        double d = 4.0;
        stack.print(cout);
        stack.push(a);
        stack.print(cout);
        stack.push(b);
        stack.print(cout);
        stack.push(c);
        stack.print(cout);
        stack.push(d);
        cout << "Stack : ";
        stack.print(cout);
        cout << "Peek : " << stack.peek() << endl;
        cout << stack.pop() << " " << stack.pop() << endl;
        cout << "Stack : ";
        stack.print(cout);

        return 0;
    }
```

dynStack :

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstring>
    #include "dynStack.h"
    using namespace std;
    dynStack::dynStack()
    {
        stack[2];
        size = 2;
        top = 0;
    }
    void dynStack::push(double item)
    {
        if(full()) {
            grow();
        }
        stack[top] = item;
        top = top + 1;
    }
    double dynStack::pop()
    {
        if(half()) {
            shrink();
        }
        top  = top - 1;
        return stack[top];
    }
    double dynStack::peek()
    {
        return stack[top-1];
    }
    bool dynStack::full()
    {
        if(top == size-1){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    bool dynStack::empty()
    {
        if(top == 0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    bool dynStack::half()
    {
        if((size-1)/2 >= top){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    void dynStack::grow()
    {
        double newstack[size*2];
        for(int i = 0;i < top;i++){
            newstack[i] = stack[i];
        }
        memcpy(newstack,stack,sizeof(newstack));
        size = size * 2;
    }
    void dynStack::shrink()
    {
        double newstack[size*2];
        for(int i = 0;i < top;i++){
            newstack[i] = stack[i];
        }
        memcpy(newstack,stack,sizeof(newstack));
        size = size / 2;
    }
    void dynStack::print(ostream &outs)
    {
        outs << top << ", " << size << endl;
        for(int i = 0;i < top;i++){
            outs << stack[i] << " ";
        }
        outs << endl;
    }
    dynStack::~dynStack()
    {
        delete[] stack;
    }
```

Here is the output when it runs :

> Stack has been created!
>
> 0, 2
>
> 1072693249, 0
>
> 1 2.07445e-317 1 2 3 4 0 2.07342e-317 0 6.90266e-310 0 6.95328e-310
>   2.122e-314 2.07353e-317 0 -3.24318e-28 2.07342e-317 6.95328e-310 0 0 1.41629e+28 1.2724e+20 6.95314e-310 0 0 2.07441e-317 6.95328e-310 4.94066e-324 0 0 2.07342e-317 6.95328e-310 0 2.07344e-317 6.95328e-310 1.38338e-322 4.94066e-324 6.95328e-310 0 6.95328e-310 6.95328e-310 6.95328e-310 6.95328e-310 6.95328e-310 6.95328e-310 6.95328e-310 6.95328e-310 6.95328e-310 6.95328e-310 6.95328e-310 6.95328e-310 6.95328e-310 6.95328e-310 6.95328e-310 6.95328e-310 6.95328e-310 6.95328e-310 0 1.63042e-322 6.95328e-310 7.90505e-323 1.59085e-314 2.96439e-323 2.02369e-320 8.39912e-323 4.94066e-322 1.4822e-323 2.07229e-317 1.97626e-323 2.76677e-322 2.47033e-323 3.95253e-323 3.45846e-323 6.90266e-310 3.95253e-323 0 4.44659e-323 2.07342e-317 5.43472e-323 2.23475e-318 5.92879e-323 2.23475e-318 6.42285e-323 7.47521e-321 6.91692e-323 7.47521e-321 1.13635e-322 0 1.23516e-322 6.95328e-310 1.5316e-322 6.95328e-310 7.41098e-323 6.95328e-310 0 0 0 -9.28906e+105 -1.79234e+115 1.12435e-307 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   1.97666e-81 9.67227e+25 1.62348e+219 3.86082e-81 1.41475e+195 1.39012e+93 1.10474e+74 2.90131e-57 4.54684e+174 6.75079e-67 1.39804e-76 3.69626e-33 4.66418e-86 5.41473e-67 4.01832e-57 1.26058e+45 4.06567e-86 8.55074e-72 1.65546e-153 2.47713e+93 3.86326e+174 2.50522e-57 3.79156e+180 1.27241e+58 2.38705e+93 4.83844e+199 2.20538e+213 2.80205e-28 7.76325e+199 1.14493e+247 2.67583e-28 2.00783e-52 6.60911e-62 5.79451e-13 9.18656e-72 6.60911e-62 1.2193e-12 2.14169e+190 9.88779e+169 2.17145e-28 7.50417e-67 4.33383e-57 1.91907e-23 9.19158e-72 2.83717e+161 2.17096e-28 9.1916e-72 9.1647e+242 2.17096e-28 9.1916e-72 5.11531e+281 2.17096e-28 2.53736e-76 4.31946e+251 1.08845e-71 2.5458e-76 3.42223e+280 1.08845e-71 1.42179e-23 2.53491e-76 3.73035e+174 2.17096e-28 1.42179e-23 1.50195e-12 2.63685e-86 1.08845e-71 2.52152e-76 8.68541e+164 2.17096e-28 9.1916e-72 1.85937e+166 1.08845e-71 9.1916e-72 2.61683e+180 2.17096e-28 9.19149e-72 1.84036e+161 2.17096e-28 9.19153e-72 5.18703e+170 2.17096e-28 9.1915e-72 2.38222e+233 1.08845e-71 9.1916e-72 6.60021e+281 2.85505e-105 1.42179e-23 4.25708e+180 2.67583e-28 9.19143e-72 8.02211e+218 2.67583e-28 9.19149e-72 1.80229e+190 2.67583e-28 9.19149e-72 2.24784e+190 2.67583e-28 9.19149e-72 6.00646e+233 2.67583e-28 9.19143e-72 9.6544e+199 2.00783e-52 2.53938e-76 6.59097e+246 2.00783e-52 1.5009e-12 2.63685e-86 6.61004e-62 1.38632e-12 2.63685e-86 6.61004e-62 6.66181e-13 2.63685e-86 1.42179e-23 2.26652e+261 2.85675e-105 1.42179e-23 1.03404e+219 2.85675e-105 1.42179e-23 2.51252e+261 2.85675e-105 9.19156e-72 8.40707e+228 2.67583e-28 1.42179e-23 4.21761e+262 2.85675e-105 1.42179e-23 3.29384e+185 2.85675e-105 6.61004e-62 2.06642e+166 2.85675e-105 1.42179e-23 1.07066e+200 2.85675e-105 1.42179e-23 2.79455e+262 2.85675e-105 6.61004e-62 2.54105e-76 7.96799e+270 2.00783e-52 2.53838e-76 5.2219e+275 2.00783e-52 2.5414e-76 2.44473e+179 2.00783e-52 2.54445e-76 1.32529e+160 2.00783e-52 2.54443e-76 3.57297e+227 2.00783e-52 2.53801e-76 1.32529e+160 2.80205e-28 2.53801e-76 8.31897e+217 1.31585e-47 7.21691e-13 2.63686e-86 6.60909e-62 6.90618e-14 2.63686e-86 6.60909e-62 6.65183e-13 2.63686e-86 1.31585e-47 2.54442e-76 1.32529e+160 1.31585e-47 2.53735e-76 6.59097e+246 1.31585e-47 6.37762e-13 8.34445e+62 9.31477e+242 3.78452e+180 2.34718e+77 2.07591e+243 9.04774e+164 3.89028e-80 7.34039e+223 5.34158e+228 3.80984e+180 1.09463e+189 1.72016e+21 2.19748e+102 1.44264e+214 1.25054e+93 1.75138e+190 1.41315e-307 4.97481e+151 4.30153e-38 1.03863e+69 6.8Segmentation fault

Here is how the output should look :

Stack has been created!

0, 2

1, 2

1.0

2, 2

1.0 2.0

3, 4

1.0 2.0 3.0

Stack: 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0

Peek: 4.0

4.0 3.0

Stack : 1.0 2.0

Comment: Whats the error? that would help

Comment: Can you be more specific? "Can't get it to work" is too vague. Posting specific error messages or failing test cases would help.

Comment: the error message is `Segmentation fault` at end of output. but still, we can't debug the program for you

Comment: ignore that error message because thats not the output that it should be

Comment: Looks like you need to do some reading on how pointers and dynamically allocated memory work in contrast to simple arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allocate memory for your stack using new. e.g.

```
stack = new double[size];
```

Similarly, in your grow and shrink routines you need to allocate a new block of memory, copy the data over, delete the old `stack` data and then point `stack` to the new memory. Your current implementation only copies the data into a local array and then returns, which will forget the copied data.

Comment: I get the error "incompatible types in assignment of âdouble*â to âdouble [0]â" when I do that.

Comment: Don't forget to delete your data via `delete[]`.

Comment: Your `stack` member variable should be a pointer, rather than a zero-size array. You didn't show your header file, so I couldn't tell what it was declared as.

Comment: Ok. Thanks! that fixed it. I tried making it a point in my header file but I used "double * stack[]" instead of "double * stack" and that was the problem

Answer (score 0):

Pointers aren't as scary at people make them sound.

Start by understanding that computer memory is one long street of mailboxes, each mailbox represents one "byte" of land along the street; this represents the "hardware representation".

Obviously we store things larger than one byte, such as 32- or 64-bit numbers. We can translate that to our street analogy by saying "The grocery is at 100-4 RAM Street".

Instead of specifying an address range, computers achieve this by including size into the instruction to put or fetch something to memory, and this bubbles up into C/C++ through the typing system. A `char` occupies one byte, a `short` occupies two bytes (usually 16 bits), an `int` is usually 32 bits, etc.

Now, when you are working with simple code like the following:

```
int i = 1;
int* p = new int;
```

Both `i` and `p` will usually be loaded into a register. The value `1` will be copied into the first, but what does the second look like? Well, it's actually just a number - the street number of the mailboxes we've been assigned for storing another int value.

It's actually legal (on a 32-bit system) to write:

```
int i;
int* p = new int;
i = (int)p;
```

If you print i, you'll get a number. There's no magic. It's just an address.

You're catching a cab to the airport for a weekend in Paris. The driver asks which gate. You look on your ticket, it says "Terminal 23". Your ticket is a pointer. It says "23", but what you have in your hands is purely the address of where you will board your plane, it's not actually the terminal itself.

You get to the airport, you check in for your flight - flight 1110 - get to the lounge and fall asleep. You wake up 6 hours later and find: your plane has gone.

Your ticket still says "Terminal 23" - but if you go to Terminal 23, will your flight be there? No, the ticket is *only a pointer*. Terminal 23 is still there - you can go to it, and if the airport staff are asleep you can probably board a plane, but will it take you to Paris? Only if Paris is in Azerbaijan. This is what is called a "stale" pointer.

```
int* i = new int;
*i = 42; // load '42' in to the address described by i
delete i;
std::cout << *i << '\n'; // ERROR
```

When we write `delete i` or `free(i)` what we are telling the operating system is that we've vacated the memory the pointer points to. We still *have* the address, so we can still try and access the location, but this is like putting a $20 bill in a drawer in a hotel, checking out, and coming back a month later to see if it's still there... The room is, the drawer is, but is the note?

The key to pointers, give `char* p`:

. `p` is the address, it's a numeric value, you can do unfortunate things like `p = 0` which makes p a pointer to address 0.
. `*p` is the value, in this case a `char`, at the address `p`. In our airport example, `p` was 23 and the contents of `p` was 1110 (your flight number).
. `&p` is the address of p. If `p` is stored in memory, then it has an address too.
. `char**` the double star means 'address of a pointer' or a 'pointer to pointer', you could pass `&p` to a function that takes `char**`,
. `void*` sometimes you don't care what a pointer points to, you just want the address - e.g. for a function like `free`. In this case, all pointers are capable of implicit conversion to a `void*`.

HTH

Comment: The problem was that I needed declare the pointer without the brackets.